# Application config file isn't saved

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, config

My wpf app has a config file which the user can edit from within the program and save it. Once I stop the debugging and start the program again the file is resetted to its old original state. I have a feeling that the file gets overwritten when the app gets built but I don't know how I would fix that.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: oh and I marked to config file as "Copy always"

Comment: Incomplete - how and esp. where do you save that file?  You shouldn't write to Program Files.

Comment: Editable setting should have `User` scope, not `Application`, and are stored in a separate file. See [How To: Write User Settings at Run Time with C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-write-user-settings-at-run-time-with-csharp)